# Call python from module and receive output

Tags: 7

I am creating a Drupal 7 custom module and would like to call a python script from the PHP and receive back some output from the script.  I am running on a Linux OS and have the following so far:

```
    $command =  "/usr/bin/python " .  drupal_get_path("module", "mycustmod") . "/pycriptdir/pyscript.py ../../../../default/files/shapefiles/CherokeeCounty.shp";
    $output = shell_exec($command);
```

Within the python script I am using echo to pipe the output.  However, I do not get anything back into the output variable as I would expect.

Any advice on how to get this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Derek

Comment: try a simple command to make sure `shell_exec` works, then check the python

Comment: Drupalist.  This simple advice pointed me in the right direction.  It turns out that I was pointing to a wrong directory.  Thanks for you advice.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses.  The basic take-home for me here is to try a simple python script shell_exec first.  Once I did this I was able to quickly see that shell_exec was working as expected.  This in turn led me to my issue which ended up being not really related where I had some minor path issue that were throwing me off.  Perhaps drupalist advice to "try a simple command to make sure shell_exec works, then check the python" will help others with the same issue.

Derek

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are "using echo to pipe the output". Your python script should just print normally. [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) captures std out.

I tried out code like you have above and it worked for me. I would try printing out the command and trying it via ssh after cd'ing to your folder and see if that works.

Also I would try it with a very small python script and see if that works.